# spring+hiberante: how can I tell if spring has picked up all the @transactional annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have an plain simple java application that use spring 2.5.5 and hiberate 3.3.1.GA. In the other word it is not running in any container like tomcat or jboss.

I want to enable transaction control in the application by the use of annotation @Tranactional. However after many trial the application does not begin any transaction as I'd expected. (Check on the server side, sybase 12.5, using `sp_transactions`)

I have read the [doco](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) a few time and hopefully I did not miss anything.

I added     `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />` to the application context xml file that contains the bean that needs to take part in a transaction.

Can anyone suggest

1) how can I turn spring logging to find out how spring framework discovers and instrument the @Transactional java classes?

2) I am using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager` as a transaction manager. Is it correct?

3) Do I need to add any jar to enable this support?

Here is a partial listing of the relevant applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="false">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>${jdbc.connection.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${jdbc.user}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxWait">
            <value>30000</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">
                    50
                </prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                    org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">
                    ehcache.xml
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">
                    true
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">
                    true
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**EDIT:**

In case it is relevant ([Spring @Transactional concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708449/spring-transactional-concurrency)), I have use @Transactional liberally

Comment: At which method do you put the transaction (Mvc Request Methods, or normal), at the class or the interface? and it it is a "normal method" how do you invoke them (same bean or other bean). Do you use AspectJ or Spring Proxy AOP?

Comment: Does STS mark the method annotated with @Transactional, to have an AOP advice? (the small red marker on the left, next to the line number?)

Comment: @Ralph: 1) annotation at the class level; 2) I can see the small red marker in eclipse. Tooltip confirmed the methods are instrumented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. set logger for org.springframework.transaction to DEBUG
2. Depends, if you run on a real J2EE server (WAS, JBoss, ...) then you should use the provided transactionmanager; if not (tomcat, jetty) you are fine
3. [Javax transaction](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/jta) but if you use maven and hibernate you should already have it (since JTA is a hibernate dependency). Do not deploy this jar if you deploy on JBoss/WAS/... sicne this may conflict with their provided JTA.

Comment: I can see messages like: "2011-11-28 15:04:54,838  DEBUG (MyProgram.java:107) - Adding transactional method [handleBusinessLogic] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE]", so I think the spring transaction is at work. But I still cannot positively test that the transaction is happening. :-(

Comment: The ultimate test would be to execute for instance 2 inserts in your supposed transaction but make the second one fail. If you are working in a transaction then the first insert will not have been executed (committed).